# Cant see scrolls and all the elements in scrollpane

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using javaFx (and Scene Builder to design the GUI).
I have ScrollPane which contains tilePane.
[image]

I'm adding a lot of elemenets (100+ element )into the TilePane and consequently I cant see al the elements.
I thought I will see the scrolls and sroll left/right or up/down to see all the added element,
but I cant see the scrolls in the window.

```
<ScrollPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="mainPackage.InController">
   <content>
      <TilePane fx:id="tilePane" prefColumns="2" prefRows="3" />
   </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

As it is on your screenshot, you have nothing inside of your `TilePane`.

To add things to the `TilePane` in Scene Builder you need to either click and drag the thing you want onto the visual part, or onto the `TilePane` that you show us a screenshot of. The `TilePane` element in the list will "highlight" with an orange border to indicate what element in the hierarchy you're attempting to add elements.

Remember that you need to save your Scene Builder document for the changes to show in you FXML document, and vice versa. Scene Builder should detect changes to the FXML file and should prompt you to load the changes made to the FXML file onto your Scene Builder project.